# Brakes 2011 Ford Explorer

Tags: ford, brakes, explorer

My brakes on my 2011 ford explorer make a clicking noise and grind when stopping(front).  I have changed the rotors (front) and the pads twice but still get the same results.  Are there any suggestions on what to try next?

Comment: What makes you so sure it's the brakes? The noise just could come about due to the use of the brakes ... possibly a wheel bearing or something? Just throwing that out there.

Comment: it's a bad grinding when I'm slowing down.  It gets worse as the vehicle warms up.

Comment: Did you check the rear brakes?

Comment: the back brakes are fine

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. When you collapsed the calipers, did both pistons in each caliper compress fully?
2. It appears the calipers are on slide pins. Is everything moving freely? What I'm wondering is if one (or both) of the calipers is not working correctly, providing even force against one of the pads. In effect, wondering if it canting over during braking. This could cause the noise you are talking about, even with the new pads/rotors. It forces just a small part of the pad to do the work. Pull the pads from the noisy side and see if the friction material is even or not. You may need to check each side using something like a digital slide caliper. I had this issue on my truck a few months ago. The difference between one side to the other of the pad was about 2mm. Would be hard to see with the naked eye, but easily seen with the caliper.

Comment: i will def. look at the pistons fully.  It does appear to be only coming from the drivers side.